# UIColor and Graphics Context

Tags: ios, uiview, uicolor, cgcolor, cgcontextref

I have a custom UIView which draws a path like so

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents(self.color));

    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

    UIBezierPath *thePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    thePath.lineWidth = _lineWidth;

    _center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    [thePath moveToPoint:_center];

    [thePath addArcWithCenter:_center radius:rect.size.width startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI+degreesToRadians(_angle)clockwise:YES];

    [thePath closePath];
    [thePath fill];

}
```

My custom UIView also has a method to change the filling color

```
- (void) changeColor:(UIColor *) newColor {

    self.color = [newColor CGColor];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

If I call the changeColor: method with any of the predefined colors such as

```
 [UIColor redColor]
```

everything works fine. Instead if i try to give it a custom color such as

```
 UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

the color of my custom UIView flicker between white, red and blue randomly.

Any ideas of why is that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.color.CGColor);
```

instead of:

```
CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents(self.color));
```

Comment: Yep, it was exactly that. Nasty little thing. As stated in the documentation in [the Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-BCIJCGGJ) **Note that the preferred API to use is now CGContextSetFillColorWithColor.**

Answer (score 0):

When you are using this method call :

```
[UIColor redColor];
```

For optimization purposes, UIColor return an object with only 2 components because he don't need the other one. (This is made possible with the mechanism of Class clustering).

That's maybe why your code show some differences between this two colors.